# How to make "package explorer" display paths

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder

So I'm going nuts here.  I could swear at one point I had found an option to have the package explorer show paths of the files, but, I can not find this option anywhere.

Did I dream this one up?  Am I searching for the wrong identifying text?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean like 'com.google.search' package name in one line instead of folder structure?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Where did the package explorer display paths to files?  What type of path?

Comment: to the right of evey entry in the explorer, in medium grey text, was the full path of the files and folders.  It would be helpful to me because I've got a seperate workspace for each of my main version branches (due to a quirk in the way that FB handles linked resources, this was necessary).    Its obviously not mission critical, but I'm mostly wanting to finally set my mind at ease.  I've been looking for this for about two months.  Just today, I combed through the entire project properties dialog, and also the main application properties dialog, looking for this feature I remember so clearly

Comment: Local path or repository path?

Comment: local path, I think.  I don't have the mercurial repository hooked up to FB yet.

Comment: Then I'm afraid I can't help. Most version control systems have label decorations, but I don't know how to make one for local paths.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the Project Explorer instead of the package explorer? It displays file paths; irrelevant to packages.

Comment: hmm...I've added "Project Explorer" and "Navigator" to my search, and added them to my view, but neither have paths, though, from my memory, such as it is...I remember selecting some setting (checkbox, radio button) to enable the feature...

Answer (score 1):

Click here:

[image]

and then there:

[image]

Comment: If you roll over the tab where your Class is open for editing, it will show the full path.

Comment: @amy :  no...only partial paths.  I can see the full path if I right click a file in the explorer, choose properties.  But I am looking for a 'with one glance' solution...and...its something I _remember_ doing in the past...unless I just dreamt it up :D .. but the memory is so clear!